# Spawning child processing on HPC using slurm

Tags: boost, mpi, slurm, spawn, mpi4py

I encountered a problem when I wanted to spawn child processes on HPC using slurm script. The parent process is a python script, and the child process is a C++ program. Now I put the source code below:

parent process:

```py
# parent process : mpitest.py
from mpi4py import MPI

sub_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn('test_mpi', args=[], maxprocs=x)
```

child process:

```cpp
// child process: test_mpi.cpp, in which parallelization is implemented using boost::mpi
#include <boost/mpi/environment.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi/communicator.hpp>
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>
#include <iostream>
using namespace boost;


int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
boost::mpi::environment env(argc, argv);
boost::mpi::communicator world;
int commrank;
MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &commrank);
std::cout << commrank << std::endl;
return 0;
}
```

the slurm script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=mpitest
#SBATCH --partition=day
#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH -n 4
#SBATCH -c 6
#SBATCH --mem 5G
#SBATCH -t 01-00:00:00
#SBATCH --output="mpitest.out"
#SBATCH --error="mpitest.error"

#run program
module load Boost/1.74.0-gompi-2020b

#the MPI version is: OpenMPI/4.0.5
mpirun -np y python mpitest.py
```

In the above code, there are 2 parameters x (maxprocs in MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn) and y (-np in mpirun). The slurm script only ran normally when x = 1, y = 1. However, when I tried to increase x and y, the following error occurred (x = 1, y = 2):

```
[c05n04:13182] pml_ucx.c:178  Error: Failed to receive UCX worker address: Not found (-13)
[c05n04:13182] [[31687,1],1] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[c05n11:07942] pml_ucx.c:178  Error: Failed to receive UCX worker address: Not found (-13)
[c05n11:07942] [[31687,2],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpitest.py", line 4, in <module>
    sub_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn('test_mpi', args=[], maxprocs=1)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1534, in mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm.Spawn
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_OTHER: known error not in list
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_dpm_dyn_init() failed
  --> Returned "Error" (-1) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[c05n11:07942] *** An error occurred in MPI_Init
[c05n11:07942] *** reported by process [2076639234,0]
[c05n11:07942] *** on a NULL communicator
[c05n11:07942] *** Unknown error
[c05n11:07942] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[c05n11:07942] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
```

Similarly, when x = 2, y = 2, the following error occurred:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpitest.py", line 4, in <module>
    sub_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn('test_mpi', args=[], maxprocs=2)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1534, in mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm.Spawn
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_SPAWN: could not spawn processes
[c18n08:16481] pml_ucx.c:178  Error: Failed to receive UCX worker address: Not found (-13)
[c18n08:16481] [[54742,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[c18n11:01329] pml_ucx.c:178  Error: Failed to receive UCX worker address: Not found (-13)
[c18n11:01329] [[54742,2],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[c18n11:01332] pml_ucx.c:178  Error: Failed to receive UCX worker address: Not found (-13)
[c18n11:01332] [[54742,2],1] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Error in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpitest.py", line 4, in <module>
    sub_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn('test_mpi', args=[], maxprocs=2)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1534, in mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm.Spawn
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_OTHER: known error not in list
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_dpm_dyn_init() failed
  --> Returned "Error" (-1) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[c18n11:01332] *** An error occurred in MPI_Init
[c18n11:01332] *** reported by process [3587571714,1]
[c18n11:01332] *** on a NULL communicator
[c18n11:01332] *** Unknown error
[c18n11:01332] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[c18n11:01332] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[c18n08:16469] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-runtime.txt / mpi_init:startup:internal-failure
[c18n08:16469] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
[c18n08:16469] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal unknown handle
```

What I want to do is to use several nodes to run the C++ program in parallel using this python script, i.e. x = 1, y > 1. What should I modify in the python code or the slurm script?

Update: according to the advice by
[Gilles Gouaillarde](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8062491/gilles-gouaillardet), I modified the slurm script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
#SBATCH --job-name=mpitest
#SBATCH --partition=day
#SBATCH -N 2
#SBATCH -n 4
#SBATCH -c 6
#SBATCH --mem 5G
#SBATCH -t 01-00:00:00
#SBATCH --output="mpitest.out"
#SBATCH --error="mpitest.error"

#run program
module load Boost/1.74.0-gompi-2020b

#the MPI version is: OpenMPI/4.0.5
mpirun --mca pml ^ucx --mca btl ^ucx --mca osc ^ucx -np 2 python mpitest.py
```

It still shows the following error: (here `mpirun -np 2` and `maxprocs=1` were used)

```
[c18n08:21555] [[49573,1],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[c18n10:03381] [[49573,3],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpitest.py", line 4, in <module>
    sub_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn('test_mpi', args=[], maxprocs=1)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1534, in mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm.Spawn
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_INTERN: internal error
[c18n08:21556] [[49573,1],1] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
[c18n10:03380] [[49573,2],0] ORTE_ERROR_LOG: Not found in file dpm/dpm.c at line 493
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mpitest.py", line 4, in <module>
    sub_comm = MPI.COMM_SELF.Spawn('test_mpi', args=[], maxprocs=1)
  File "mpi4py/MPI/Comm.pyx", line 1534, in mpi4py.MPI.Intracomm.Spawn
mpi4py.MPI.Exception: MPI_ERR_INTERN: internal error
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is
likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can
fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment
problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some
additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI
developer):

  ompi_dpm_dyn_init() failed
  --> Returned "Not found" (-13) instead of "Success" (0)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
[c18n10:03380] *** An error occurred in MPI_Init
[c18n10:03380] *** reported by process [3248816130,0]
[c18n10:03380] *** on a NULL communicator
[c18n10:03380] *** Unknown error
[c18n10:03380] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[c18n10:03380] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
[c18n08:21542] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-runtime.txt / mpi_init:startup:internal-failure
[c18n08:21542] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
[c18n08:21542] 1 more process has sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal unknown handle
```

Comment: as a workaround, try `mpirun --mca pml ^ucx --mca btl ^ucx --mca osc ^ucx ...`

Comment: I tried `mpirun --mca pml ^ucx --mca btl ^ucx --mca osc ^ucx -np 2 python mpitest.py` and I set maxproc to be 1. However, it still shows some error. I put this in my problem above.

Comment: since you are requesting 4 tasks in slurm, you start 2 tasks with `mpirun`, and all the tasks `MPI_Comm_spawn()`, you can only spawn with `maxprocs=1` (otherwise you ask for more slots than what you allocated). Do you have the same issue if you `mpirun -np 1 ...` and `maxprocs=1` ? Does the code work outside of SLURM?

Comment: The code works with `mpirun -np 1 ...`  and `maxprocs=1`. The code with `-np` >1 and `maxprocs=1` also shows error outside of SLURM.  It shows  `All nodes which are allocated for this job are already filled.` when I ran this with `salloc -p interactive -c2 -n2 -N1` and `mpirun --mca pml ^ucx --mca btl ^ucx --mca osc ^ucx -np 2 python mpitest.py`.

Comment: Actually, what I want to do is to run this C++ code in parallel using mpi4py. I don't know if spawning new processes is the best choice. But simply using `os.system(mpirun test_mpi)` in the python script and `mpirun -np x python mpitest.py` does not give any output. So I tried to use the Spawn function

Comment: if you want to `mpirun -np 2 ...` you need to `salloc -n4`

Comment: If you only want to write a python script that will launch a MPI program, and there is no communication between the script and the MPI program, then I suggest you keep it simple and `os.system("mpirun ...")` if your script (that does not `import mpi4py`, and you do not start via `mpirun`).

Comment: Unfortunately, the C++ program will be a part of  the python program, and the other parts are written in mpi4py. So I tested if I can launch a c++ program in parallel in a mpi4py environment, but I did not find a simple solution other than writing a python interface in C++ using pybind11 and directly call the function in python.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean, so let's get pedantic. Do you want to spawn a standalone program? or do you want to call a C++ library from a python program?

Comment: Well, the work flow is like this: 1. python program prepare the input of C++ program -> 2. C++ does the calculation and gives an output -> 3. python reads the output and goes on. Now in step 1, the python program is written in mpi4py and should be executed in parallel. In step 2, the C++ program is written using boost::mpi. So what I want to do is to either directly run the C++ binary in parallel (which I have not found any way to do) or write an interface to call the C++ function.  So I wonder if there is any method to directly  run the C++ binary using mpi4py in parallel.

Comment: One issue with the `MPI_Spawn()` approach is you need more slots (e.g. 2 for python, 2 for C++) when there are only 2 slots "active" at a time(e.g. python is waiting when C++ is working). So in this case, I'd rather suggest you turn your C++ program into a library you invoke from python. note the C++ library should **not** invoke `MPI_Init()` nor `MPI_Finalize()` since `mpi4py` takes care of it.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestions, I'll try to write a python interface for the C++ program.